# How to convert string to date format

Tags: java, string, date

I want to convert `3/13/2014 11:38:58 AM` string to date format.

I see some examples but and also implement but I don't know how to convert AM/PM to 24 hour time format.

How to make it possible ?

Comment: checkout [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").parse(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can convert your date and time..

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date date_current =  new Date();
Date date_start = null;
date_start = sdf.parse("3/13/2014 11:38:58 AM");
System.out.println("now time is.." + date_start);
```

Thanks..

Comment: one part of answer is missing *AM/PM to 24 hour time format*

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing Strings into Dates:**
The SimpleDateFormat class has some additional methods, notably parse( ) , which tries to parse a string according to the format stored in the given SimpleDateFormat object. For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*; 
public class DateDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

  String input = args.length == 0 ? "1818-11-11" : args[0]; 

  System.out.print(input + " Parses as "); 

  Date t; 

  try { 
      t = ft.parse(input); 
      System.out.println(t); 
  } catch (ParseException e) { 
      System.out.println("Unparseable using " + ft); 
  }
 }
}
```